# TreeView directories in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview

I have this code in C# Windows Form Application, but I need it in WPF. Do you have any ideas?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListDirectory(treeView1, "C:\\Users\\Patrik\\Pictures");
}

private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
}

private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));

    return directoryNode;       
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In WPF instead of `Nodes` property is `Items` property and instead of `TreeNode` you should use `TreeViewItem` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

```
   private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Items.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }

    private static TreeViewItem CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = directoryInfo.Name };
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            directoryNode.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            directoryNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = file.Name });

        return directoryNode;

    }
```