# C# converting a list to a hierarchy

Tags: c#, list, hierarchy

Hej hej,

i'm currently working on a c# wpf project where i want to dynamically populate a TreeView from a linear list of Items.

My starting point was this article on codeproject:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

John Smith shows how to use the HierarchalDataTemplate withing TreeViews. So far this is working. My problem is to dynamically generate a hierarchical Tree from a linear list of items. I have tried to adapt the solutions found here

[Mapping a flat list to a hierarchical list with parent IDs C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532262/mapping-a-flat-list-to-a-hierarchical-list-with-parent-ids-c-sharp#25532561)

and here

[TreeView directories in C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954669/treeview-directories-in-c-sharp-wpf)

but somehow i did not succeed.

My item class looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ItemPath[] ParentPath { get; set; }      

    public ItemPath[] Path { get; set; }
}
```

ItemPath class

```
public class ItemPath
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Targeted hierarchial class

```
public class ItemTree
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public List<ItemTree> ChildTree { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this flat list to test my methods:

```
var items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item()
    {
        Name = "item 0",
        Path = new ItemPath[]
        {
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Red", Level = 1 },
        }
    },
    new Item()
    {
        Name = "item 1",
        Path = new ItemPath[]
        {
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Red", Level = 1 },
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Green", Level = 2 },
        }
    },
    new Item()
    {
        Name = "item 2",
        Path = new ItemPath[]
        {
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Red", Level = 1 },
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Violet", Level = 2 },
        }
    },
    new Item()
    {
        Name = "item 3",
        Path = new ItemPath[]
        {
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Blue", Level = 1 },
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Black", Level = 2 },
        }
    },
    new Item()
    {
        Name = "item 4",
        Path = new ItemPath[]
        {
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Blue", Level = 1 },
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Green", Level = 2 },
        }
    },
    new Item()
    {
        Name = "item 5",
        Path = new ItemPath[]
        {
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Red", Level = 1  },
            new ItemPath() { Name = "Green", Level = 2 },
        }
    },
};
```

My goal is to have a hierarchy like this

- [Red]

  - item 0
  - [Green]

    - item 1
    - item 5
  - [Violet]

    - item 2
- [Blue]

  - [Black]

    - item 2
  - [Green]

    - item 4

My current attempt is below. It's the rewritten version of the stackoverflow post from above:

```
// class to create dummy data as described above
var dummyData = new DummyData();
var items = dummyData.CreateTier2DummyList();

var cat = items.Select(r => new ItemTree()
{
    Path = r.Path,
    Item = r,
    // parent path is generated dynamically
    ParentPath = r.Path.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray(),
}).ToList();

var lookup = cat.ToLookup(c => c.ParentPath);

foreach (var c in cat)
{
    if (lookup.Contains(c.Path))
        c.ChildTree = lookup[c.ParentPath].ToList();
}
```

Somehow i think that using an array as the path and parent path is not a good idea. But it reflects an absolute path (comparable to a file path in a file system).

Comment: Have you thought of using [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to build the hierarchical strucure?

Comment: hey, no i've never heard of that. Maybe i have to learn something new. Do you know a good example?

Comment: Nevermind, just need to scroll down the wiki-article :-)

Comment: What's the data format used for input to be converted to a hierarchical list? Are `Item` and `ItemPath` types you've created to facilitate building the tree?

Comment: Are Item and ItemPath types you've created to facilitate building the tree? -> Yes

Comment: Edit: Actually it's just ItemPath and ItemTree, Item is the business object i want to use. It has even more properties, i just simplified it to post it here. ItemPath is a property i want to use to faciliate the ItemTree, it is not necessary for the business logic. Finally i use a list of ItemTree to bind it to a WPF view in a MVVN manner.